# how to implement a calendar into my app

Tags: android

I have a social app and it works using calendars. I have been looking for how to integrate, say, a google calendar into my app, but the API documentation is pretty confusing. Is there any advice somebody could give me? Or is there a wrapper out there I can use? I want to be able to create, edit, and remove events from a calendar in my app. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  that code with base: http://code.google.com/p/android-calendar-view/.

Is Apache License, enjoy!

The official Android [Calendar Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html) and API was only introduced in Ice Cream Sandwich (API v14). I hope this tutorial help you [Get Started with the Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/)

Comment: I actually wanted a way to access the google calendar, not just a way to display it. Thank you though